# Hide static Java methods from Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

We're converting a lot of java static methods to kotlin extension functions.  However, there are some methods that we need to keep around JUST FOR JAVA (We want to force kotlin code to use the extension functions).

Is there a way to hide java static methods from kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate those methods with a `@Deprecated` annotation with deprecation level HIDDEN:

```
@kotlin.Deprecated(message = "JUST FOR JAVA", level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN)
public void foo() {
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. This make it invisible to Java too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can try `DeprecationLevel.ERROR`

Comment: I don't think there's another solution.

Comment: One thing I tried was to mark the functions as `internal` in Kotlin, and then set the name of the function manually with @JvmName("myJavaOnlyFunction"), which works, but IDEs like JetBrains will complain that you're using an internally-marked function.

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution. It's a bit of a hack, but works perfectly:

```
@kotlin.SinceKotlin(version = "99999.0")
public void foo() {
}
```