# Mark a fun / property for use in Kotlin / Java only

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, backwards-compatibility

I'm currently writing a KOTLIN class were I like to use the possibility of DSL but be backwards compatible for JAVA developers. When using a `var` the compiler automatically creates getter and setter for JAVA, but those can't be used Builder style since they are not returning `this`.

So basically what I like to do is something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    // for use in KOTLIN only DSL style e.g. MyClass() { offset = 1 }
    var offset: Int? = null

    // for use in JAVA only BUILDER style e.g. new MyClass().withOffset(1)
    fun withOffset(value: Int) = apply { offset = value }
}
```

In Kotlin I like to use, but don't want to have access to the `withOffset` fun:

```
val myClass = MyClass() { offset = 1 }
```

In JAVA I like to use, but don't want to have access to the auto created `setOffset` and `getOffset`:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass().withOffset(1)
```

Renaming the getter and setter is possible via `@JvmName` annotation already, but is there a annotation for hiding a public property for JAVA completly and optional of course vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot hide a constructor, while you can make a so called fake-constructor using `operator fun invoke` in which you can use a [@JvmSyntheic](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-synthetic/) annotation to hide it from the java.

And to hide a function from kotlin you can use [@Deprecated](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/) with [DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecation-level/-h-i-d-d-e-n.html#kotlin.DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN).

*Note: The [@JvmField](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) will instruct the compiler not to generate the default getter and setter for your var*

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    @JvmField
    var offset: Int? = null

    @kotlin.Deprecated(message = "JUST FOR JAVA", level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN)
    fun withOffset(value: Int) = apply { offset = value }

    companion object {
        @JvmSynthetic
        operator fun invoke(init: MyClass.() -> Unit) = MyClass().apply(init)
    }
}
```

Usage in kotlin:

```kotlin
MyClass() { offset = 1 }
// or
MyClass { offset = 1 }
```

Usage in java:

```java
MyClass().withOffset(1)
```

Resources:

- [Hide static Java methods from Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613604/hide-static-java-methods-from-kotlin)
- [What's the intended use of @JvmSynthetic in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022275/whats-the-intended-use-of-jvmsynthetic-in-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks you for the quick answer. The deprecated method doesn't seem to work anymore. This is also mentioned in the reference you provided. There is also a trick mentioned which does work `@kotlin.SinceKotlin(version = "99999.0")` ... Not sure if I should use it. Hiding from Kotlin is not so important anyways. I will now try `@JvmSynthetic`. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: @tekgator Deprecated still works, testing with Kotlin1.4-M1. See it shows Unresolved reference in playground as well 1.3.72 https://pl.kotl.in/Qjc5_WM4i

Comment: Sorry maybe misleading comment. Indeed it hides it in Kotlin, but in Java as well. Error = Method Call expected, just like the method doesn't exist at all

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do something like this in Kotlin

```kotlin
val myClass = MyClass() { offset = 1 }
```

but I would suggest you do do this instead, it looks much nicer in my opinion.

```kotlin
// It's a inline function so there's no runtime overhead.
inline fun buildMyClass(builder: MyClass.() -> Unit): MyClass {
    return MyClass().apply(builder)
}

class MyClass {

    @JvmSynthetic
    var offset: Int? = null
        private set

    fun withOffset(value: Int) = apply { offset = value }
}
```

So you can call it like below

```kotlin
val myClass = buildMyClass {
   withOffset(0)
}
```

In Java, it looks like this:

```java
final MyClass myClass = new MyClass().withOffset(0);
```

Comment: `MyClass() { offset = 1 }` is possible if you accept a receiver lambda in constructor as you did in `buildMyClass`